# Send form results to another page php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hello I have a form working properly using

```
php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']
```

The results are shown on same page as form.

I need to be able to send the form data and results to another page (eg `results.php`) when the user submits the form.

How is this achieved?

Comment: `<form action='results.php'>...`

Answer (score 1):

Just point the form action to results.php

```
<form action="results.php">
 <!--Inputs-->
</form>
```

Or if you need to do a redirection store **$_GET** at **$_SESSION['parameters']** .

Comment: Hello Cody this opens new page ok but no results / data are passed over??

Comment: You need to fill the form with Input's and datas you need to pass from the form .

Answer (score 1):

Here are some attributes of form tag `<form>` you need to set them..

```
<form action="controller.php" method="post">
 <!--form elements-->
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" />
</form>
```

Here when ever the submit button clicked, it will submit the form to its action i.e. `controller.php` by `post` method (i.e. form elements' value won't display in query string).

Later you can access their value on `controller.php` by `$_REQUEST['element_name']` or `$_POST['element_name']` or `$_GET['element_name']` according to the form method type.